# Asymmetric Encryption - How is the Public Key Being Shared?

Tags: public-key, terminology

I've been reading up on the relationship between private keys and public keys (as well as hashing), and I watched a few videos, but I am still a bit confused.

I don't have a programming background, and I want to be able to explain these things to an "everyday person".

What I found is that before a message is "**encrypted**" with a "**public key**" that key FIRST must be shared with the receiver.

How is the public key being shared?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This isn't an English question, but the public key can be shared in any way you wish. It does not need to be kept secret because it is used only for encoding, which is why it has to be shared "first", but with the transmitter. The receiver already knows it and gives it to the transmitter, to encode the message. For decoding, the private key is used and must not be shared.

Comment: A discussion of **Public-key cryptography** can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know that this forum is structured in such a way.

Comment: Usually the key is shared by just distributing it (e.g. as e-mail attachment, via keyservers or in the situation where it's needed). The really interesting question is how it is shared such that the recipient _knows_ that the key belongs to the claimed entity.

Comment: ah, for sure it is. Lets see what else we can get.

Comment: Also, look up the Diffie-Hellman exchange - it's what is used a lot - especially when two people don't have prior knowledge of each other (ie public keys). But it's also off topic because it's not public-key infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

The key is shared via email, via scp/rsync/ssh-copy-id (remote copy), or by editing the settings of your account on a website. If you look in a web application that supports PKI, there will be an option under settings where you can upload your public key. Running an agent on your trusted OS machine (which has your private key) allows automatic verification via custom client software. It will understand you have an agent, then verify your local private key against the server's known public key.

The metaphor used is that of an empty box. You give a friend a padlock, but you keep the key. They put valuables in the box, and close the padlock you gave them on the box.  Now only you can open the box and get the valuables. The public key is the padlock. The private key is the key. Imagine that anyone can have the same padlock all over the world, but only you can open whatever they send you.